# My coworker shared private information outside of work

Tags: colleagues

I live in Colorado, recently my mother passed suddenly. I informed my employer and took a day off, the following week a coworker shared outside of the office to a non employee that my mother passed away. I was then contacted by the 3rd party. 
I am very upset by this and my employer tells me nothing can be done. Is there something I can do to hold the coworker accountable for her actions?

Comment: Yes I have, this is not the first time she has shared personal info outside of the office, I did not share my mothers passing with her my employer did

Comment: @user92145 Can you prove that?

Comment: @user92145 - You might want to note that your mother's passing is (in Colorado, at any rate) **not** a matter of public record; https://law.justia.com/codes/colorado/2016/title-25/vital-statistics/article-2/section-25-2-117

Comment: If your employer doesn't want to do anything, your only options left are basically to talk to a lawyer (although I can't imagine you'd have much to gain over trying to fight this, not to mention your chances of winning), move on (forget about it) or move on (find another job). Although this seems more like an issue with your employer sharing information they shouldn't share, rather than this employee (unless this employee needs this information to do their job... somehow).

Comment: @Dukeling - Agreed. This is (at best) a very minor violation of company confidentiality laws and OP would need to actively prove that this communication was the sole way that this employee could have learned this information. Assuming this individual isn't going to be punished by her company and lawyers up immediately if faced by legal action, then there's no possible sanction they could face other than the annoyance of having to repeatedly defend her actions and the cost of a nuisance-suit.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by accountable for her actions? I take it you may be upset this info was shared in such way, but it is no clear how this affects you or your work...

Comment: "*Vital statistics records shall be treated as confidential*". That means that they're not part of the public record. Only those with a direct interest (such as relatives or financial partners) have a right to this information.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Information shared in confidence with their employer via the correct HR channels is part of your staff record. If you could show that this person overheard it from another employer then that would obviously be a different matter.

Comment: Sorry for your loss, but I don't understand the problem. Why would you want to hide the fact your mother had passed.

Comment: "I informed my employer." Did you say to that person "Please keep the reason confidential for now"? It's not unnatural for coworkers to ask about an absent colleague 'Did something happen to user92145?' and then the reason leaked out.

Comment: I think the issue here is about the fact that the info was shared and now 3rd parties are contacting

Comment: Just to reiterate, embarrassing or inconvenient information is not legally protected as "confidential". If the employer posted your personal health information, then **that** would be illegal according to HIPAA law in the USA.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to hear of your mom's passing. Certainly that is upsetting.

You should talk to your boss/employer (if you assume that was the one who shared your information within the company) and ask that things be kept private in the future.

You cannot control what your coworker says outside of work. That's free speech.

And if you truly don't want specific information shared, you should not even tell your employer. Gossip tends to get around.

Comment: It's not free speech in Colorado to share [confidential information](https://law.justia.com/codes/colorado/2016/title-25/vital-statistics/article-2/section-25-2-117) gleaned through a work communication that was given with an expectation of privacy.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's a violation of state laws regarding staff data confidentiality. IANAL but I'm pretty sure that taking information that was communicated in confidence *to the company* and sharing it with a non-employee would be something that would be actionable. You'd need a lawyer to root out the relevant state laws but the link above shows that info about someone dying isn't something that is part of the public record.

Comment: Hmm. A very brief look at Colorado law would suggest that her actions were in violation of the precedent set by [ROBERT OZER v. BORQUEZ](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/co-supreme-court/1361186.html), to whit "*public disclosure of private facts"* that resulted in extreme offense. The fact that was disclosed is a private one (one not part of the public record), that resulted in distress and that was shared in confidence.

Comment: The case dealt with the sharing of private information that the plaintiff found distressing to have shared. I'm reasonably sure the two situations equate sufficiently that a good lawyer could get OP her day in court if she felt like wasting a lot of money on a fool's errand

Comment: @Richard - Births, deaths and marriages are very much in the public domain.

Comment: @Richard OZER v. BORQUEZ doesn't apply here - a) the disclosure would fail the  2nd test for "invasion of privacy" - *The requirement of public disclosure connotes publicity, which requires communication to the public in general or to a large number of persons, as distinguished from one individual or a few*. There's nothing in the OP to suggest that more than a few people were given this information. And b) I don't believe the "vital statistic" angle that you mention means what you think it does - the confidentiality there refers to the Death Certificate, not that the death occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do about it. But you learned a valuable lesson from the ordeal.

You can speak with your boss and explain that you are upset that information was shared as you confided information to him/her and then he/her shared it with others without your consent. But I'd leave it at that and not push any further. Just know that moving forward if you need time off just say it's for personal reasons and if he/she pushes then just tell him/her that you'd rather not give any details because you'd rather others in the office not be aware of your personal life events.

It's a very valuable lesson I've learned from watching something similar happen to a guy at work. He told our manager that he was going to be taking some time off from work because he found out his wife was cheating on him and he wanted to try and save his marriage. The manager told a number of people in the office while he was out and when he came back people kind of mocked him and ultimately he ended up quitting over the treatment.

But honestly, what would you want to happen? Somebody to be fired? Everything has repercussions when interacting with your superiors. I mean you might have the footing to stand and argue your point here but what happens if the manager is a vengeful person? What would you gain by pushing for some kind of HR action? Just let him/her know that your upset over it (professionally) and then move on knowing that you can't really count on that person to keep things to themselves.

Comment: That guy had a pretty solid case against his employer, both for sharing confidential information and for the workplace bullying that resulted.

Comment: @BillLeeper for bullying? Probably.
For "confidential information"? Highly unlikely. Confidential information is stuff that is likely to cause legal damages (bank account info, medical history, Social Security number, etc.). This does not cover information that is merely inconvenient or embarrasing.